# Why can't I add a firewall exemption for inbound HTTP and HTTPs?

Tags: windows, azure, server

[image]
I have made an Azure VM that I want to use as a server.  However, when I input the VMs IP address into a browser, I am always given a timeout message.  I understand that I need to allow inbound connections in the firewall settings, but there seems to be no option to do this in advanced firewall settings.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:  These are the network settings I currently have:
[image]

Comment: You need to at a inbound security rule for port 80(HTTP) or port 443(HTTPS) . You can do this through the **Networking** blade inside your VM in the Azure Portal.

Comment: @RoadRunner I have done this see you can see in picture above.  I really don't get what is wrong.  I can RDP to the VM fine.

Comment: Try enabling IIS. Run Install-Module -Name Web-Server inside the VM in powershell admin mode. Then you should be able to see a webpage when accessing your VM in a browser

Comment: are you sure the correct NSG is linked to your VM network interface? I see two NSG's in your photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access your websites with the public IP address of your Azure VM. Actually you access from an external network. You need to [open ports to a virtual machine with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) if you have a network security group attached to a subnet or a VM network interface. You can check the NSG setting from virtual machine----networking on the Azure portal.

For example,

Create an **inbound security rule** allowing traffic and assign values to the following settings:

**Destination port ranges**: 80,443

**Source port ranges**: * (allows any source port)

**Priority value**: Enter a value that is less than 65,500 and higher in priority than the default catch-all deny inbound rule.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks for the help Nancy.  I tried everything you suggested and I added inbound security rules for HTTP and HTTPs.  I made sure the priority value was low.  However I am still unable to access the website from an external network.  Do you think I need to change the settings in the VMs firewall too?

Comment: By default, the Azure VM is open to port 80. Since you have NSG configured, could you temporarily turn off the windows firewall to verify it? If no effect, try to telnet your port from the local machine and check the service port is listening on the Azure VM. such as `netstat  -anbo`

Comment: I have tried turning off the firewall - no luck.  I then ran 'netstat -anbo' and got a surprise.  port 3389 is listed as listening (so RDP is fine) but there is no listing for ports 80 or 443.  Not sure what to do about this...

Comment: @Matthew What happens when you run `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName IP_ADDRESS -Port 80`?

Comment: It means no service is listening on port 80, Do you enabled the webserver role via install `Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server` as admin privilege on PowerShell or https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/step-by-step-setup-iis-on-azure-windows-virtual-machine/

Comment: @NancyXiong Ah thats the correct command. I for some reason suggested `Install-Module -Name Web-Server ` in the comments above, which is incorrect :P